# Binding a setter value inside a trigger to an element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to give a different header to an `Expander` when it is closed. When the value is constant, everything works well, but when I try to bind the header to a DP (e.g. `Presenter`) in my control it doesn't work. Here is my simplified markup:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.PlanDisplayer"
             xmlns=...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
             x:Name="This">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Expander>
            <Expander.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Expander" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ChildExpanderStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="Header">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!--Works-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Presenter.Walls.Count, StringFormat='Walls:  [{0}]'}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Header">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <!--Doesn't work → Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding-->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PlanDisplayer, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Presenter.Walls.Count, StringFormat='Walls  [{0}]'}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Expander.Style>

            ...
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: can you confirm if you are actually binding to an `event`?

Comment: Well, yes. Could be thought like I am binding to an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the same `TextBlock` and apply a `Style` to it:

```
<Style TargetType="Expander">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Presenter.Walls.Count, StringFormat='Walls:  [{0}]'}}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Presenter.Walls.Count, StringFormat='Walls  [{0}]'}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8. It works but would you explain why you restructured the markup like this? I'd like to learn the rule. Is it just because of the ability of DataTrigger to get bound to elements?

Comment: Basically because the same TextBlock is always a visual descendant of the UserControl and then you know that the binding works.